# Getting Calculated Expression to Display Properly in Powershell Exchange Command

Tags: email, powershell, exchange-server

So I have a command to look at all the mailboxes in my environment and return the oldest item in any folder that is not the "Contacts" folder of that particular mailbox. The whole thing seems to work except for the calculated expression that I threw in at the end of the command:

```
@{Name="Address";Expression={Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}
```

The problem is this seems to return every Smtp Address for each line/object instead of one Smtp Address per line/object.

Here's the entire command:

```
Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -IncludeOldestandNewestItems -Identity $_.Alias | Where-Object {($_.OldestItemReceivedDate -ne $null) -and ($_.FolderPath -ne "/Contacts")} | Sort OldestItemReceivedDate | Select First 1 OldestItemReceivedDate, Identity, @{Name="Address";Expression={Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {$_.PrimarySmptAddress}}}}
```

Ideally this would return the date of the oldest item, the folder where it was found, and the primary SMTP Address but it doesn't seem to be pulling only the corresponding SMTP Address. It looks like it's pulling every Primary SMTP Address every iteration. I'm sure it's something with my command but I can't figure out where. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculated expression has access to the current pipeline object. However you are not using that when creating your expression. You are just calling *every* mailbox for each user as you have seen. Use the current pipeline object with `$_`. `Get-Mailbox` is smart enough to match needed values by property name.

```
 @{Name="Address";Expression={Get-Mailbox $_ | ForEach-Object {$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}}}}
```

However you might be able to go about this is a different way. You already called all mailboxes at the start of your pipeline. No sense calling it a second time again.

```
Get-Mailbox | Select-Object Identity, @{Name="Address";Expression={$_.PrimarySmtpAddress}}, @{Name="OldestItemReceivedDate";Expression={
    Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -IncludeOldestandNewestItems -Identity $_.Alias | Where-Object {
            ($_.OldestItemReceivedDate -ne $null) -and ($_.FolderPath -ne "/Contacts")} | 
            Sort-Object OldestItemReceivedDate | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty OldestItemReceivedDate -Last 1      
}}
```

Now we have 2 calculated properties and we only need to call `Get-Mailbox` once for each user. You have some spelling mistakes and logic errors that I tried to fix. You will know if it does what you want.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! I had to re-configure it a bit to get the Folder Path to display as this displayed the Identity property from Get-Mailbox but that was no big deal.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3591385 Glad I could help. Consider marking this answer as accepted if this did help you.